# How to fix function declaration formatting in PhpStorm (2020.1.2) if signature longer then defined row length?

Tags: phpstorm, code-formatting

For example I have function declaration like this:

```
public function someLongMethodWithLongParamName(int $longparamName): VeryLongReturnValueType {}
```

with row length limit that less than chars count of function signature.

If I type `Ctrl + Alt + L` PhpStorm will format this row, but in strange way:

```
public function someLongMethodWithLongParamName(int $longparamName
): VeryLongReturnValueType {
}
```

(PhpStorm left parameter in the line of method name). If I will add one more parameter, PhpStorm will format line correct:

```
public function someLongMethodWithLongParamName(
    int $longparamName,
    bool $flag
): VeryLongReturnValueType {
}
```

Maybe someone deal with such bug?

P.S. Here are my Code Style settings:

[image: code style]

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug and how would you like this to be formatted?

Comment: @Ástþór As I understand OP wants same as code sample #3 but with only 1 parameter present (which is the same as code sample #2 but with a new line between `(` and `int`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want it to wrap parameter & its type also? Then remove the `Place ')' on new line` checkbox in `Method declaration parameters` settings from your screenshot.